# Creating an accelometer in CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, charts

Im working on a project where I need to visualize the G-force on a spaceship. I want to accomplish this with creating an accelometer (something like a seismogram see picture for an example)
Is is possible to create this using CSS/JavaScript?
The accelometer needs to run infinite creating random data for the G-force on the spaceship.[image]

Comment: you will need some charting library

Comment: Try some libraries like highcharts and d3js

Comment: Im using Chart.js but I can't find the right one for my example

Comment: you should check D3.js
maybe something like this: 
https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/d3-band-chart

Comment: This is super broad.  If your question is "is it possible", then... yes, yes it's possible.  I expect your question is more than that, though.

Comment: @arielb This chart is what I want, but it is static and does not change. I want to code one that creates random data every 5 seconds.

Comment: @Blank, you can do that with the example i have sent you .
As you can see , where they fetch the data, you can put a setInterval for each 5 seconds and pull new data.

Answer (score 1):

It sure is possible with CSS and JS.

**The question is wether you want to do it that way.**

If I were you I'd choose to use the HTMLCanvasElement to display the data generated by either JavaScript on the client side or the server side language of your choice on the server.

Comment: HTML5 Canvas is awesome, very versatile and easy to use. I would also recommend it.

Comment: Please not that the data changes every (few)seconds because we're talking about G-force it is not static

Comment: Sure thing @Blank the HTM5 Canvas allows dynamic data to be displayed

Comment: Can you give me a simple example on how to achieve this?

Comment: @Blank Have an array of data wich you add new datasets to every so often. Then set up a draw loop using requestAnimationFrame and draw the data in the array to the canvas

Comment: The data should be generated automatically and not added by me, or I create a dataset with a few data that just loops itself so it looks like random generated data

Comment: How you add your data to the array is another story. You can generate random values each time though.@Blank